# how to get notified of start of a terminal session

Tags: c#, notifications

I want to disable an app when terminal services start. Is there a way to register with some service that will notify when some logs in remotely?

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to get notified of it but you can periodically check [SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.terminalserversession.aspx) and act accordingly.

However, if your program doesn't work through RDP the people who want to use it remotely will just use VNC. Or TeamViewer. Or other methods. Suffice to say that I consider it poor behavior or a program to not work remotely in an RDP session and even actively avoiding to do so.

Comment: thanks! However the app in question is a Synergy server. It works as designed except that when in RDP I dont actually need it to work :) . I dont want to be closing windows on other machines :) unknowingly.

Comment: @murlex: Ah, sorry then :-). I just came across a few applications that refused to work in RDP environments just because they didn't want customers to use them on a Terminal server, so I kinda assumed you wanted to do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I suggests you listen to ETW events raised by WMI around the RDP objects, like [Win32_SessionDirectorySession](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383637%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [Win32_Terminal](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383638%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), [Win32_TSRemoteDesktop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb736367%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) and other. There are various articles describing how to wrap MOF queries into ETW sessions:

- [Intro to Event Tracing For Windows](http://blogs.msdn.com/matt_pietrek/archive/2004/09/16/230700.aspx)
- [ETW Tracing: How and Why?](http://blogs.msdn.com/matt_pietrek/archive/2005/03/23/401080.aspx)